# How get header token to avoid XMLHttpRequest flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, xmlhttprequest

I'd like to download the JSON file which can be accessed by this url https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/prufungssimulation-caff9.appspot.com/o/5qPfjoZjdNXyN5Ob2q3pFbj5MKy1.json?alt=media. Every time I call the function I get a Error: XMLHttpRequest error. After some researches I found that this error could be avoided by adding my API token in the header. Something like

```
    headers: {
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Basic your_api_token_here', //here i want my token
    },
```

But I have no clue how to get my api Token. Does anybody know how to fetch this token? May this error be caused becaus I run it on chrom flutter?

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

[...]
[...]


void testFunction(){

    var url_string = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/prufungssimulation-caff9.appspot.com/o/5qPfjoZjdNXyN5Ob2q3pFbj5MKy1.json?alt=media";

    var result = await getJsonFromFirebaseRestAPI(url_string);

    print(result);
}

Future<String> getJsonFromFirebaseRestAPI(String url) async {

    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    return response.body;
  }
```

The JSON file result should look like this:
`routes: []`
It's basically empty I'm just trying to implement the function.

I use `http: ^0.13.5`

I get the following error:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 299:10
createErrorWithStack
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 341:28
_throw
dart-sdk/lib/core/errors.dart 116:5
throwWithStackTrace
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1378:11
callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11
_microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5
_startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15
<fn>
```

Can anybody solve my issue?

Appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it works perfectly. You just need to add `async` to `testFunction()`. You have no need for JWT.

Examples:

```
void testFunction() async{
  var url_string = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/prufungssimulation-caff9.appspot.com/o/5qPfjoZjdNXyN5Ob2q3pFbj5MKy1.json?alt=media";

  var result = await getJsonFromFirebaseRestAPI(url_string);

  print(result);
}

Future<String> getJsonFromFirebaseRestAPI(String url) async {

  http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

  return response.body;
}
```

or

```
try{
  final response = await Dio().get(    'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/prufungssimulation-caff9.appspot.com/o/5qPfjoZjdNXyN5Ob2q3pFbj5MKy1.json?alt=media',
  );
  print(response.data);
}catch(e){
  print(e.toString());
  if(e is DioError){
    print(e.response!.data);
  }
}
```